# Grouping and Counting arrays in rethinkdb

Tags: rethinkdb, reql

I have json data as follows:

```
{

"artist": {
    "aliases": {
        "name": "Thaddeuz Anderson"
    } ,
    "data_quality": "Correct" ,
    "id": 2377 ,
    "name": "DJ Thadz" ,
    "namevariations": {
        "name": [
            "D. J. Thadz" ,
            "D.J. Thadz" ,
            "DJ Thaz" ,
            "Thadz"
        ]
    } ,
    "profile": "" ,
    "realname": "Thaddeuz Anderson"
} ,
"id": "040a5506-5d4a-4beb-a27b-90f7cf3b0a69"

 }
 {

"artist": {
    "data_quality": "Correct" ,
    "id": 2273 ,
    "name": "Riff HiFi" ,
    "namevariations": {
        "name": "Riff Hiffi"
    } ,
    "profile": ""
} ,
"id": "041bdd4d-f7ae-4bb0-b971-88f252281421"

 }
```

I want to find the number of aliases for every artist.

So I am using the following command:

```
r.table('artists')('artist')('aliases').group('name').count()
```

The result I get is 1 in reduction. How do I get the total number of elements in the aliases array? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you `group` something, you need to then `ungroup` it. So, for your query, you need to add `ungroup` at the end.

```
r.table('artists')('artist')('aliases').group('name').count().ungroup()
```

That being said, If all you want is get the number of aliases for every artist, `group` is not really the method for that. You're better of using `merge` to append an alias count to the document.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for you reply. I wanted to index it instead. Is there some way to do this? My main intention is to check whether there are artists with more than 3 aliases.

Comment: I tried this : r.table('artists').filter(r.row('artist')('aliases')('name').count().gt(3)). However, I am getting an error called "cannot convert string to sequence

Comment: I think the first thing you need to do is convert the `aliases` object in an array. Then you can just do this `r.table('artists').filter(r.row('artist')('aliases').count().gt(3))`

Comment: If you want to index it, you can just create an index with an index function: `r.table('artists').indexCreate("aliasesCount", function (row) { return row('artist')('aliases').count(); });` (that won't work until you change `aliases` into an array). After creating the index you can just do this: `r.table("artists").getAll(3, { index: "aliasesCount" });`

Comment: Ok. I used this command. 

         r.db('discogs1').table('artists').filter(r.row('artist')('aliases')('name').typeOf().eq('ARRAY')).filter(r.row('artist')('aliases')('name').count().gt(2)). 

There were already arrays present. I will also look into the indexing . Thanks a lot.Couldn't have done it without you :)

Comment: Glad to help! BTW, you can also write a query to convert all the non-arrays into arrays. That might be an option.